# Can't save image from API with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-api

I want to save an image from my react app in my rails app. 
I post this to my api:
[image]

and when I try to save it i get this error:

```
{  
   "file":[  
      "has contents that are not what they are reported to be",
      "file type is not acceptable"
   ],
   "file_content_type":[  
      "file type is not acceptable"
   ]
}
```

my model looks like this:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence: true

  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :file, styles: { square: "350x233#", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :file, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/, message: 'file type is not acceptable'
  validates_attachment_size :file, less_than: 10.megabytes, message: 'file size is more than 50MB'
end
```

and my controller:

```
def create
    uploaded_file = false

    if params[:photo][:image]
      tempfile = Tempfile.new(params[:photo][:filename])
      tempfile.binmode
      tempfile.write(Base64.decode64(params[:photo][:image]))

      uploaded_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
        :tempfile => tempfile,
        :filename => params[:photo][:filename],
        :original_filename => params[:photo][:filename],
        :content_type => Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(params[:photo][:filename])[1..-1]).to_s
      )

      params[:photo][:file] = uploaded_file
    end

    params[:photo][:title] = params[:photo][:filename] if params[:photo][:title] == ""

    # @picture = Photo.new(photo_params)
    @photo = current_user.photos.build photo_params
    @photo.save

    render json: @photo.errors
  end
```

and in my logs i found this:

```
Unpermitted parameters: :image, :filename
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/homepage.jpg20180415-7-1wa7yr3'
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/homepage.jpg20180415-7-1wa7yr3 to /tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-jpgu5m.jpg
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-jpgu5m.jpg to /tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-147ntu1.jpg
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-147ntu1.jpg'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename homepage.jpg (application/octet-stream from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
  [1m[35m (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
[paperclip] Trying to link /tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-jpgu5m.jpg to /tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-ndp9hd.jpg
Command :: file -b --mime '/tmp/ba3988db0a3167093b1f74e8ae4a8e8320180415-7-ndp9hd.jpg'
[paperclip] Content Type Spoof: Filename homepage.jpg (application/octet-stream from Headers, ["image/jpeg"] from Extension), content type discovered from file command: application/octet-stream. See documentation to allow this combination.
```

I didn't get my mistake. Can anyone help me with that upload?
I think the content_type is missing, but I don't know where.

Comment: your log shows Unpermitted parameters: :image, :filename, did you add image  in strong parameters in the controller

Comment: When I add "image" I get: unknown attribute 'image' for Photo. My Database don't have a image column. My column for the file is "file". In image is my base64encoded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `Paperclip`'s `io_adapter` to decode the base64 into the attachment object? Something along the lines of:

```
def create
    file = Paperclip.io_adapters.for(params[:photo][:image])
    file.original_filename = params[:photo][:filename]
    @photo = Photo.new(file: file, user: current_user)
    @photo.save
end
```

Comment: Yep, after hours of work I got it working a few days ago. But I must add this `Paperclip::DataUriAdapter.register` to my Paperclip initializer.